# How many people could hear the prophet's speech at Ghadir?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

I've heard that Muhammad (PBUH) gave speech before 120,000 Muslims at Ghadir at the final Hajj of him. So, for how many people was it possible to hear what he was saying? Even if one spoke loudly in front of 1000 people, they would have difficulty to fully understand the speech, let alone 120,000 people. So how was anybody hearing anything at all?

Comment: Could you please include reference or narration or at least where you read this, any thing to back up your claim? It would help in producing an answer

Comment: 'Aisha said about verse 58:1 subhan Allah I was in the same room and couldn't hear what the Prophet and the woman were speaking about, but Allah could. So why should Allah not make it possible to hear a speech by all the audience? An other rather not faith based possibility is that our Messenger always used to say something like:"May the present tell the absent"

Comment: @Aboudi https://www.al-islam.org/ghadir/incident.htm "*This was first time that the Muslims with this magnitude gathered in one place in the presence of their leader, the Messenger of Allah [s]. On his way to Makkah, more than seventy thousand people followed Prophet [s]. On the fourth day of Dhu'l-Hijjah more than one hundred thousand Muslims had entered Makkah.*"

Comment: @Medi1Saif "*Upon receiving the verse, the Prophet [s] stopped on that place (the pond of Khumm) which was extremely hot. Then he sent for all people who have been ahead in the way, to come back and waited until all pilgrims who fell behind, arrived and gathered.*" - Saying "May the present tell the absent" does not make sense here because "*he sent for all people who have been ahead in the way, to come back*". There is no doubt he wanted everybody, present and absent, to hear the speech.

Comment: @Meysam I'm afraid that this might be shi'a view or narration only! And historians used to exaggerate numbers (this is still usual in cultures like the Arabic culture a high number is just used to emphasize that there were many people it doesn't necessarily give the real amount) many modern scholars and orientalists doubt the amount of people quoted in the books of early Muslim historians to some extent.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Then can you cite a reliable reference as to how many people have been gathered on that day?

Comment: @Meysam no as I never did search for that, I only wanted to say that one should have this in mind, as even in some ahadith (sunni) there are claims with very high numbers that are explained by scholars that the amount is only an indication of the importance or used to emphasize. Of course Muslim sources speak of some 100000 who have assisted fath Mekka.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If scholars exaggerate and cannot be relied on for their reports, the question is, who should we rely on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45688/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-meysam).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether people where able to hear him or not, however that isn't impossible taking into consideration the possibilities below:

- They may have used a communication method similar to that used by a
  historic military leader to address an army of 100,0000 or more, they
  must have used some method to assure that everyone received the
  instructions issued by a leader(will find what that method may be)
- The position of the speaker and landscape can have an influence on of
  where the sound waves may travel and reach, (i.e. those standing at
  the bottom of the valley can easily hear those standing at a higher
  altitude rather than on the same altitude and distance) might be
  because there will no objects for sound waves to collide with, thus
  can travel further
- There could be another person quoting the speaker, for example if you
  observed how the prayer is carried out in some mosques, you'd realise
  that in some of them some one repeats the Imam with a higher voice to
  make sure that the rest heard it (For example he may say Allahu Akbar
  after the Imam has said it)
- Not quite sure how many people can fit in historical theatres (when no sound
  systems where available), but it would be at least in the
  1000s, I'm sure the audience must of heard the show somehow.

**References coming soon**

One thing to note, is how was this number known in the first place, I doubt any one was in charge of head account.